# Is using "it" after the em dash ungrammatical here?

Tags: grammaticality, pronouns, punctuation

> The thought of going to that scary mansion again—it paralyzes me.

This sentence should be *The thought of going to that scary house again paralyzes me.*

Is it ungrammatical after adding the em dash and *it*? Why or why not?

Comment: em dashes imitate speech or afterthoughts. It depends on ***what you want to say***.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Lambie says in a comment, this em dash is intended to represent spoken English in text.

The speaker says "The thought of going to that scary house again"  And then they pause. This isn't a complete sentence, but the speaker leaves it as a fragment.

Then the speaker starts again with a complete sentence "It scares me", where "It" refers to the fragment uttered before.

The em dash represents the pause. It is dramatic and rhetorical in nature.

Of course in some sense, speaking a fragment is "ungrammatical". The first part isn't a complete sentence. But not every utterance is a grammatically complete sentence.

As a representation of natural speech, this is fine.